# Nmap same site different computer different results

Tags: network, nmap, network-scanners

I'm running `nmap somesite.com` on my local machine and I get the following results:

```
Host is up (0.026s latency).
Not shown: 942 closed ports, 50 filtered ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE
21/tcp   open  ftp
22/tcp   open  ssh
80/tcp   open  http
443/tcp  open  https
5060/tcp open  sip
5500/tcp open  hotline
8008/tcp open  http
8010/tcp open  xmpp
```

I then ssh into my aws instance and run the same command, but I consistently get:

```
Host is up (0.098s latency).
Not shown: 996 closed ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE
22/tcp   open  ssh
80/tcp   open  http
5000/tcp open  upnp
5500/tcp open  hotline
```

Both my local machine and server are running Ubuntu 16.04. I'm wondering why I would get such different results?

Comment: My initial thought is that aws doesn't like some traffic to be generally allowed for one reason or another.

Comment: There are a number of networking and firewall questions one would need to ask about your AWS instance. Check those first.

Comment: @schroeder if I remember correctly aws defaults to unrestricted outgoing traffic and only has default restrictions for incoming.

Comment: Where is the target you are scanning? (i.e the internet, your LAN, same enterprise network but different VLAN.)

Answer (score 1):

I guess `somesite.com` is external for your local machine and for your AWS machine too (I guess is not another AWS machine).

As people said in comments, at first sight it seems AWS is blocking some kind of traffic and from your AWS machine to `somesite.com`. There are some firewall restrictions.

But there are something strange on this... for example, you are "losing" port 443 which is a very common port used for SSL connections. And usually that port is not blocked by default even in AWS. So clearly your AWS machine has a special configuration or maybe is not your machine, is your AWS environment. Ask to the admins or if you are the admin, ask to Amazon.